# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'getKey'

Tags: python, hashtable, attributeerror

I try to make a simple hashtable in python with linear probing. My hash table is working but I have some problems with my perfomance testing method.

I am just getting an AtrributeError in the follwing code:

This is my performance method:

```
def performance(lin_prob=True, rand_input=True):
    '''
    Prints the average runtime of k insert operations
    for different sizes of key

    Args:
        lin_prob - whether linear probing or
            double hashing should be used
        rand_input - whether input should be randomized
            or a predefined (worst case) input
    '''

    m = 1009  # first prime bigger than 1000

    # repeat for increasing number of keys
    sizes = [math.floor((m * i) / 50) for i in range(1, 50)]
    for k in sizes:

        ht = HashTable(m, lin_prob)

        if rand_input:
            inputs = random.sample(range(10 * m + 1), k)
        else:
            inputs = [m * i for i in range(k + 1)]

        start_time = time.time()
        for key in inputs:
            ht.insert(key)

        total_runtime = (time.time() - start_time) * 1000000
        avg_runtime = total_runtime/k  # average time in nano sec

        print("%d\t%.2f" % (k, avg_runtime))
```

I am getting the AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'getKey', which is referencing to this line `ht.insert(key)`

There is a conflict with my insert method:

```
 def insert(self, entry):
        '''
        Method inserts key into hash table
        according to the hash value of the key.

        Args:
            key - key to insert

        '''

        key = entry.getKey()
        index = self.hash(key)
        count = 0
        if self.table[index] == None or self.table[index].getValue() == "DELETED":
            self.table[index] = entry
            return count + 1
        else:
            inserted = False
            step_size = self.hash_method(key)
            while inserted != True:
                index += ste_size
                count += 1
                if index >= self.size:
                    index = index - self.size
                if self.table[index] == None or self.table[index].getValue() == "DELETED":
                    self.table[index] = entry
                    return count
```

This line `key = entry.getKey()` is making the error referencing to the line in my performance method.
Is there another way to implement the line in the performance method?
Or how can I avoid this error? I am just a little newbie in programming, please help me.

Comment: your `key` variable it's just an integer, cause your list `inputs` is a list of integers. Integers has no getKey() method

Comment: but it is working without the performance method. Is there a simple way to change the ht.insert(key) line? i just want to iterate about all the integers

Comment: what is `getKey()` ? Standard `list` and `dict` don't have it. And `int`, `float`, `str` don't have it. It seem like you try to use `entry` like some more complex object but we don't know what you try to do. OR maybe you need only `key = entry` ?